# Documentation for Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.Role?

Tags: reporting-services, scripting, reportingservices-2005, deployment

Zilch on the web or BOL

Any ideas?

Comment: What is BOL?  What are you trying to find exactly?

Comment: Properties associated with this object. BOL = SQL Server Books Online

Answer (score 0):

You mean this one here, in the SQL Server 2005 Books on line...?

[Role Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2005.role.aspx)

> Represents a role for use in Reporting
>   Services security.
>
> Namespace: ReportService2005 Assembly:
>   ReportService2005 (in
>   reportservice2005.dll)

Comment: I'd hardly class such gems as "Represents a role for use in Reporting Services security" as documentation. Nothing is mentioned regarding methods/properties associated with such an object. Looks like the usual autogenerated Microsoft documentation.

Comment: It's in BOL though, which is what you asked... ;-)